# How can I ignore one blur listener when a different click listener is used in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

So it's kind of hard to put into a sentence but here is a simple example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#input").focus(function() {
                    $("#p").show();
                }).blur(function() {
                    $("#p").hide();
                });
                $("#p").click(function() {
                    alert("Thanks for clicking me");
                });
            });
        -->
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="input" />
        <p id="p" style="background:red;display:none"">
            Click me.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically when you focus on an input a paragraph appears and when the focus is blurred the paragraph disappear.  However there is also a click listener on the paragraph so when you click it an alert messagebox appears.  The problem is when I focus the input box the paragraph appears [expected] but when I click on the paragraph the blurring of the input box is registered first so the paragraph is hidden before the browser detects I clicked on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Ben Alman's jQuery Outside events plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/)

Then your code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input").focus(function() {
        $("#p").show();
    }).bind('focusoutside', function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).is('#p')) {
            $("#p").hide();
        }
    });
    $("#p").click(function() {
        alert("Thanks for clicking me");
        // Do this if you need to hide #p after doing 
        // whatever click on p really does.
        $(this).hide(); 
    });
});
```

By using the focusoutside event it will capture both clicking and tabbing away from `#input` and will let you decide based on where the focus went want to do.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/WSEWh/2/

Comment: Don't you need the $("#p").hide() in the click function then?

Comment: @mikesir87 Depends on what he wants to do when `#p` gets clicked. But most likely yes.

Comment: Sounds great! I didn't know about using the event object, so that was pretty useful.  Thanks!